# AngularJS ng-repeat not updating DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar, directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am creating a simple calendar directive using AngularJS. Everything works fine (ie. it renders correctly and changes month as you would expect).

However, when the month changes and the scope is updated Angular renders the calendar correctly but all the DOM nodes created in ng-repeat have the same id's as the one's in the last array (the month before). I've tried using the **track by** clause but to no avail.

Here is my code (TypeScript):

```
testApp.directive('calendar', () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            startDate: '=?'
        },
        link: (scope: any, element, attrs) => {
            var today = new Date(),
                dayNames = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
            //monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

            angular.extend(scope, {
                dayNames: dayNames,
                weeks: []
            });

            var startDate;
            if (scope.startDate) {
                try {
                    startDate = scope.startDate = new Date(scope.startDate);
                } catch (err) {
                    startDate = scope.startDate = today;
                }
            } else {
                startDate = scope.startDate = today;
            }

            function EvaluateCalendar(date, callback?: Function) {
                scope.weeks = [];
                var monthStart = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1),
                    monthEnd = new Date(date.getFullYear(), (date.getMonth() + 1), 0),
                    daysInMonth = monthEnd.getDate();

                var startPadding = monthStart.getDay(),
                    endPadding = dayNames.length - (monthEnd.getDay() + 1);

                var totalMonth = GetTotalMonth(startPadding, daysInMonth, endPadding);
                var monthWeeks = GenerateWeeks(totalMonth);
                scope.weeks = monthWeeks;
                console.dir(scope.weeks);
                if (callback) callback();
            }

            function GetTotalMonth(startPadding, daysInMonth, endPadding): Array<any> {
                var totalMonth = [],
                    daySpacer = {
                        id: '',
                        currentMonth: false,
                        weekend: false,
                        date: ''
                    };
                for (var i = 0; i < startPadding; i++) {
                    var preSpacer = Object.create(daySpacer);
                    preSpacer.id = 'pre' + i;
                    totalMonth.push(preSpacer);
                };
                for (var j = 0; j < daysInMonth; j++) {
                    var day = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), j + 1);
                    totalMonth.push({
                        id: day.toISOString().split('T')[0],
                        currentMonth: true,
                        weekend: (day.getDay() == 0 || day.getDay() == 6),
                        date: day
                    });
                };
                for (var k = 0; k < endPadding; k++) {
                    var postSpacer = Object.create(daySpacer);
                    postSpacer.id = 'post' + k;
                    totalMonth.push(postSpacer);
                };
                return totalMonth;
            };

            function GenerateWeeks(totalMonth): Array<any> {
                var monthWeeks = [];
                var currentWeek = [];
                $.each(totalMonth, (index, item) => {
                    currentWeek.push(item);
                    if ((index + 1) % 7 === 0) {
                        monthWeeks.push(currentWeek);
                        currentWeek = [];
                    }
                });
                return monthWeeks;
            };

            EvaluateCalendar(startDate, () => {
                scope.$watch('startDate', (newValue, oldValue) => {
                    if (newValue != oldValue) EvaluateCalendar(new Date(newValue));
                });
            });
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', ($scope, $element) => {

            $scope.nextMonth = () => {
                var startDate: Date = new Date($scope.startDate);
                $scope.startDate = startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + 1);
            };

            $scope.previousMonth = () => {
                var startDate: Date = new Date($scope.startDate);
                $scope.startDate = startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 1);
            };

        }],
        template: '<div class="calendar">' +
        '<div class="month-header">' +
        '<div class="month-control-group">' +
        '<a href="#" class="month-btn month-prev" ng-click="previousMonth()"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-fw"></span></a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="month-btn month-next" ng-click="nextMonth()"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></span></a>' +
        '<h3>{{ startDate | date: \'MMMM yyyy\' }}</h3>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="header">' +
        '<div class="day-name" ng-repeat="dayName in dayNames">{{ dayName }}</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="week" ng-repeat="week in weeks">' +
        '<div id="{{ day.id }}" class="day" ng-repeat="day in week track by day.id" ng-class="{ weekend: day.weekend }">' +
        '<span class="day-header">{{ day.date.getDate() }}</span>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

Example: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/andrewcourtice/pen/ZYybXw)

Note: *My JavaScript isn't great so if you know of a better way to write this that would be a huge help. I know there is the AngularUI calendar but i'd just prefer to write my own to learn.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you say something more? How does html directive call look alike? How do you change the month?

Comment: create a demo in plnkr.co or jsfiddle.net so others can see it and fork any possible changes

Comment: @charlietfl I have edited my question to include a Codepen example of the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: so what steps should i take to see problem

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry I forgot to mention that part. Click the next and previous buttons on the calendar. The class being applied to the weekend days should only be getting applied to the days that fall on a weekend. However the class is not being re-evaluated when the month is changed and the highlighted days move into the week. The other issue is the day cells' Id's are not being updated with the new id (a date in ISO format). If you're using Chrome use the Chrome dev tools to inspect the day element and take note if the Id. Thanks.

Comment: I only looked at it briefly ... I suspect you have a stray `startdate` somewhere. Keeps switching between `var startdate` and `$scope.startdate` try renaming one of them. Also if you set brekpoints in code can step through and inspect values at varios points